# Angular 2 http post trying to simulate a form

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-http

I'm making an ionic2 app that needs to authenticate to an existing php site and then perform some requests inside it. I don't have any control or access to the source of the site.
Since I'm using ionic2 I shouldn't have CORS issues, I also manually disabled it in chrome for testing purpose

I made a service that does the login request to the page at data/login.php
The problem is that the login always fails and _body is always "".

Also I don't know how to get and store that cookie that gets set to keep the session.

Here's the relevant code of the login service:

```
doLogin(username, password) {

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('usr', username);
    params.append('psw', password);
    params.append('invia_annuario', 'Accedi');


    this.http.post(this.loginPage, params.toString(), { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(
        data => {

            console.log(data);


        },
        Error => { console.log(Error) },
        () => { console.log("Done") }
        );
}
```

Here's what the real request from a browser looks like

Proper request:

```
POST /data/login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: [website]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 55
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: [website]
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.33 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.lions.it/data/login.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

request data:
`usr=[username]&psw=[password]&invia_annuario=Accedi`

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2016 13:34:24 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.33
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Refresh: 0; URL=./index.php
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6qp5p3f8tm7bm3hqgttfqk20m1; path=/
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

my manufactured request:

```
POST /data/login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: [website]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 55
Origin: http://localhost:8100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.33 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=android
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ua37v7sgojddlnt2d961t5gu33; legatus_post_views_count_22=1
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2016 13:28:11 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.33
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Refresh: 0; URL=./index.php
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

How do I properly send a request to the remote site and how do I get that session cookie?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `set` method instead to build the form data:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('usr', username);
params.set('psw', password);
params.set('invia_annuario', 'Accedi');
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/DknaczJrInjDnmOkLR6r?p=preview.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything different, I'm still getting the same response with an empty body and no other clues

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use? I use this way the `URLSearchParams` class...

Comment: In my case and with your code, the request is correctly sent. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/DknaczJrInjDnmOkLR6r?p=preview.

Comment: I tried your sample with my own data but I can't even run it, I only get an error in the console:

Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
 Error loading https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from https://run.plnkr.co/w7Tyly21c2f5fhvV/src/main.ts

Anyway the requests does get sent in my code too, the problem is that I don't know how to make use of that cookie that gets sent me back, since I can't even find where it